# costume button clickable for website..like this one

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, button

i got this code

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <!--<script src="app1.js"></script> -->
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css"/>

</head>

<body>
  <div id="clickdiv" >Start</div> 
  <button  onclick="countTracker()">OneButton</button> 
  <script type="text/javascript">

      var clickCount = 0;
      function countTracker() {
          clickCount += 1;
          document.getElementById("clickdiv").innerHTML = "Clicks:" + clickCount;
          localStorage.setItem("count", clickCount);

      }
      str_count = localStorage.getItem("count");
      console.log(str_count);
    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

but how its possible to make the button like this
http://ak8.picdn.net/shutterstock/videos/2577947/preview/stock-footage-eject-button-on-a-white-background.mp4

Comment: What do you mean by like this the design/style ?

Comment: yes the design..i mean i want to but the eject button that i show you..not the normal button that i got now

Comment: You could run an animated gif, or use the html5 canvas tag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is little example how you can make it.. :)

```css
button {
    outline: 0px !important;
    border: 0px;
    position: relative;
    color: #FFF;
    background-color: red;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 25px;
    display: block;
    cursor: pointer;
    text-shadow: 0px 2px 3px #AFAFAF;
    padding: 4px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
    -moz-border-radius: 50;
    border-radius: 50;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 12px 0px rgba(150,0,0,1), 0px 12px 25px rgba(0,0,0,.7), 0px -3px 15px rgba(0,0,0,0.3) inset;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 12px 0px rgba(150,0,0,1), 0px 12px 25px rgba(0,0,0,.7), 0px -3px 15px rgba(0,0,0,0.3) inset;
    box-shadow: 0px 12px 0px rgba(150,0,0,1), 0px 12px 25px rgba(0,0,0,.7), 0px -3px 15px rgba(0,0,0,0.3) inset;
    margin: 100px auto;
 width: 100px;
  top: 0px;
  height: 80px;
 text-align: center;
 
 -webkit-transition: all .3s ease;
 -moz-transition: all .3s ease;
 -ms-transition: all .3s ease;
 -o-transition: all .3s ease;
 transition: all .3s ease;
}
button:hover {
    border: 0px !important;
    outline: 0px !important;
}
button:active {
    border: 0px !important;
    outline: 0px !important;
    position: relative;
    top: 13px;
      -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 3px 0px rgba(150,0,0,1), 0px 3px 6px rgba(0,0,0,.9), 0px -3px 15px rgba(0,0,0,0.3) inset;;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 3px 0px rgba(150,0,0,1), 0px 3px 6px rgba(0,0,0,.9), 0px -3px 15px rgba(0,0,0,0.3) inset;;
    box-shadow: 0px 3px 0px rgba(150,0,0,1), 0px 3px 6px rgba(0,0,0,.9), 0px -3px 15px rgba(0,0,0,0.3) inset;;
```

```html
<button>Eject</button>
```

Comment: thnx about that :) but how i can remove the blue aruond the button http://prntscr.com/81k2fh

Comment: Editted my answer and removed blue outlines around button.. basically jus add 
    outline: 0px !important;